# why "short_url" not showing in res.json with the unique ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing APIs and Microservices projects on FreeCodeCamp,the "Url shortener microservice". Here is my code:

```
const shorturlSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  originalUrl: String,
  shortUrl: Number
});

const ShortUrl = mongoose.model("ShortUrl", shorturlSchema);

app.post("/api/shorturl/new", urlencodedParser, async (req, res) => {
  var url = req.body.url;
  console.log(url);
  if (!validUrl.isWebUri(url)) {
    res.json({ error: "invalid url" });
  } else {
    var newUrl = new ShortUrl({
      originalUrl: url,
      shortUrl: shortId.generator
    });
    try {
      await newUrl.save();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("error", err);
      return res.json({
        error: "failed to store in database"
      });
    }
    res.json({
      "origianl_url": newUrl.originalUrl,
      "short_url": shortId.generate
    });
  }
});

app.get("/api/shorturl/:short_url?", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.short_url);
  const smallUrl = req.params.short_url;
  if (smallUrl === undefined) res.json({ error: "undefined" });
  else {
    const actualUrl = await ShortUrl.findOne({ shortUrl: smallUrl });

    res.redirect(actualUrl.originalUrl);
    return;
  }
});
```

It should respond with a `{"original_url":"www.google.com","short_url":1}`. But instead it shows `{"origianl_url":"https://www.freecodecamp.org"`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use async, or change the place of `await newUrl.save();`

Comment: @feedy I don't think that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the shortUrl from the database object.

Edited code:

```
try {
      const response = await newUrl.save();
      return res.json({
          "origianl_url": response.originalUrl,
          "short_url": response.shortUrl
      });
    } catch (err) {
      return res.json({
        error: "failed to store in database"
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made some changes in the code. In the schema:

```
const shorturlSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  originalUrl: String,
  shortUrl: {
    type:String,
    default:shortId.generate
  }
});
```

Then in the app.post section

```
 var newUrl = new ShortUrl({
      originalUrl: url
    });
```

Then finally in the res.json part of app.post

```
res.json({
      "original_url": newUrl.originalUrl,
      "short_url": newUrl.shortUrl
    });
```

This gives me the output:

```
{"original_url":"https://www.freecodecamp.org","short_url":"_sAInwNXs"}
```

I just figured this out now. Thanks for all your help